# Nexus 5, low space problems

Tags: internal-storage, storage, nexus-5

I recently got nexus 5 16GB, but I have weird storage problem. The OS should take about ~3.5GB, so I should have 12.55GB left for apps and stuff. BUT:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image to enlarge)</sup>

4.66GB + 2.95GB + ~0.5GB IS NOT 12.55, but ~8GB. Where is the remaining 4GB space?

Comment: via a terminal app (or `adb shell`), execute `df -h`. This shows you all partitions, the used, and the free space along. My guess is the remaining space goes to `/system` (reserved space for possible future updates), `/recovery`, `/boot`, and `/cache`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thumbnail cache**

Check the `.thumbnails` directory in `sdcard/DCIM (Digital Camera IMages)/`  notice that it is a hidden directory and only visible with certain file managers with the option to view hidden files.

This directory stores a lot of thumbnail data especially in the form of two large binary files.

**Play Music** (if you are using it)

Play Music caches your songs so `Settings > Clear Cache`.

**App Data left behind**

Delete some app data cache left behind by uninstalled apps from `sdcard/` and `sdcard/Andorid/data`. Even apps such as Chrome, Maps, YouTube leave a lot of cached files in `sdcard/Andorid/data`. Clean those apps cache from `sdcard/Andorid/data`.

**Storage Space**

Install [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) and check your devices storage by detail.

*DiskUsage provides a way to find files and directories on storage card which consume a lot of space.*

After pinpointing down apps and files that consume a lot of storage with DiskUsage. Simply deleting those files and going into `Settings > Apps` selecting and cleaning those apps would prove sufficient.